# Insert picture inside box in css

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I wanted to insert an image inside my box and additionally I wanted to insert texts also below the image as a sort of a description for the supposed image inside the box. How would I implement that?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sen:wght@700&display=swap');
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.content{
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.banner{
  background-image: url("banner.png");
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 7rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -20px 50px  black;
  display: flex;

}
.container-content{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
h3{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0;
}
h3:hover{
  background-color: #9e9b9b;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: -17px;
  padding-top: 17px;
}
.sidebar{
  height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  display: flex;
  min-width: 245px;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.sidebarlogo{
  max-width: 245px;
}
.header{
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #5c5b5b;
  padding-top: 17px;
}
.menu a{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 15px 6px 15px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu a:hover {
  min-width: 100%;
  Background-color: #1b1b1b;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.fa-building-columns{
  padding-right: 12px;
  font-size: 39px;
}
.fa-books{
  padding-right: 12px;
  font-size: 39px;
}
.fa-users{
  padding-right: 12px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.fa-megaphone{
  padding-right: 12px;
  font-size: 36px;
}
.fa-arrow-right-from-bracket{
  padding-right: 12px;
  font-size: 39px;
}
.mcm{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10rem;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x=icon" href="form.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="IP.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.1/css/all.css">
    <title>Institution Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <aside class="sidebar">
      <span>
        <img class="sidebarlogo" src="sidebarlogo1.jpg">
        <div class="header">
            <h3>Welcome to the Institution Page!</h3>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="menu">
          <a href="IP.html" class="p"><i class="fa-regular fa-building-columns"></i>Institution Page</a>

          <a href="#"><i class="fa-light fa-books"></i>Courses</a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-light fa-users"></i>Student Roster</a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-regular fa-megaphone"></i>Announcements</a>

          <br><br><br><br><br><br>

          <a href="labtask 6.html"><i class="fa-light fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>Log out</a>
        </div>
      </span>
      </aside>

      <main class="content">
          <div class="banner"></div>
          <div class="container-content">
                <div class="mcm" >
                    asdfsdfd
                </div>
          </div>
      </main>

</body>
</html>
```

Ignore the "asdfsdfd". I wanted to insert an image there and have some sort of a title header below the image and finally, add some description text for the image. Any solutions for this is highly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

itry to answer and help. It might help you. and i share the fiddle link too https://jsfiddle.net/pw7e5Lca/5/

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sen:wght@700&display=swap');
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.content{
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.banner{
  background-image: url("banner.png");
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 7rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -20px 50px  black;
  display: flex;

}
.container-content{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
h3{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0;
}
h3:hover{
  background-color: #9e9b9b;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: -17px;
  padding-top: 17px;
}
.sidebar{
  height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  display: flex;
  min-width: 245px;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.sidebarlogo{
  max-width: 245px;
}
.header{
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #5c5b5b;
  padding-top: 17px;
}
.menu a{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 15px 6px 15px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu a:hover {
  min-width: 100%;
  Background-color: #1b1b1b;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.fa-building-columns{
  padding-right: 12px;
  font-size: 39px;
}
.fa-books{
  padding-right: 12px;
  font-size: 39px;
}
.fa-users{
  padding-right: 12px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.fa-megaphone{
  padding-right: 12px;
  font-size: 36px;
}
.fa-arrow-right-from-bracket{
  padding-right: 12px;
  font-size: 39px;
}
.mcm{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10rem;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}
.item__img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: right;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 100%;
}
div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x=icon" href="form.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="IP.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.1/css/all.css">
    <title>Institution Page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <aside class="sidebar">
      <span>
        <img class="sidebarlogo" src="sidebarlogo1.jpg">
        <div class="header">
          <h3>Welcome to the Institution Page!</h3>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="menu">
          <a href="IP.html" class="p"><i class="fa-regular fa-building-columns"></i>Institution Page</a>

          <a href="#"><i class="fa-light fa-books"></i>Courses</a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-light fa-users"></i>Student Roster</a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-regular fa-megaphone"></i>Announcements</a>

          <br><br><br><br><br><br>

          <a href="labtask 6.html"><i class="fa-light fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>Log out</a>
        </div>
      </span>
    </aside>

    <main class="content">
      <div class="banner"></div>
      <div class="container-content">
        <div class="mcm">
          <div class="img_bos">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-a-picture-of-the-beautiful-view-of-birds-1836263689.jpg" class="item__img" />
          </div>
          <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
          <div class="img_bos">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-a-picture-of-the-beautiful-view-of-birds-1836263689.jpg" class="item__img" />
          </div>
          <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

  </body>

</html>
```